# Find Which script or workflow is sending mails

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I got a Netsuite CRM system from a client where already there are 100+ workflows and scripts implemented and running.

One of the consumer of client is getting system generated emails from netsuite on Daily basis which they want to stop. Say the mail id is abc@xyz.com

Client asked me the same, now my question is how to find which workflow or script is generating the mails or is there any simpler way to block the mails sent to that id?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Rahul

Comment: With that many scripts etc, I'd consider blocking the emails at the email-client-level. You could also try a saved search of workflows, where you might find an email field. Maybe also check the raw email header for clues. One last thought: if you can export all the scripts, try a full text search for the email address. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply.

The best option I found was sending that mail id to Netsuite support and asking them which workflow/script is really sending the mails to which they replied.

Once that was done then I found it to be a workflow which had a saved search that was giving the data.

I went to the record from the saved search and I was able to stop the mails.

Any ways thanks for your time.

Glad

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to do some dig through with your email and its content.

1. Check the content of the email and check for the email reason. Ex. Order Completed, Payment Pending
2. From this you can identify from which record mail is being sent.
3. Check the Messages sub tab under General tab of the Customer record for the author of the email.
4. Download all Scheduled Scripts with deploy status as Released and open all the script files and use Find all method with the authoremailid and authorinternalid

Thanks
Frederick

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found:

1. Get the mail id.
2. Search it in global search
3. It will give corresponding record.
4. Open the record and in bottom go to system information.
5. Check the Active workfow and check that work flows you will find your answer.

Thanks
Gladiator